# trouble using Function with data type struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

My assignment has given me a function prototype, `Apartment get_apartment_info();`, that I need to use, which asks me to do this:

> function should prompt the user for all the information about an apartment, store it an Apartment variable and return it.

I don't know how I would go about accomplishing this, but what I have tried returns this error after I input all the information:

> free pointer(): invalid pointer signal: aborted (core dumped)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Apartment {

  Apartment get_apartment_info() {
    cout << "enter building number: ";
    cin >> building_number;
    cout << "enter apartment number: ";
    cin >> apartment_number;
    cout << "enter apartment type: ";
    cin >> apartment_type;
    cout << "enter view: ";
    cin >> view;
    cout << "enter your name: ";
    cin >> renter_name;
  };

  int building_number;
  int apartment_number;
  string apartment_type;
  string view;
  string renter_name;
  double amount_due;
};

int main() {
  Apartment complex;
  complex.get_apartment_info();
}
```

Since this isn't the way to achieve what I am trying to, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Move the function outside the struct. Inside the function declare an `Apartment` variable, input the data into the member variables in that struct, then return it.

Answer (score 0):

With [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) in mind, my answer is:
You are actually almost there. The last ingredient you need is how to return a struct as a value. I will show some simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point make_point(int x, int y){
    return Point{x,y};
}

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    Point MyPoint = make_point(3,4);
    cout << "My point is:" << MyPoint.x <<", " << MyPoint.y << endl;
}
```

`return Point{x,y};` is the point I want to emphasize. You need the function which returns an `Apartment`, right? Modify this syntax to make appropriate return Apartment class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't follow the directions you were given:

> function should prompt the user for all the information about an apartment, **store it an Apartment variable and return it**.

Your function promises to return an `Apartment` object, but it doesn't return anything at all, which is **undefined behavior**. So the code crashes when it tries to destruct a non-existant object.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Apartment {

  Apartment get_apartment_info() {
    Apartment result;
    cout << "enter building number: ";
    cin >> result.building_number;
    cout << "enter apartment number: ";
    cin >> result.apartment_number;
    cout << "enter apartment type: ";
    cin >> result.apartment_type;
    cout << "enter view: ";
    cin >> result.view;
    cout << "enter your name: ";
    cin >> result.renter_name;
    return result;
  };

  int building_number;
  int apartment_number;
  string apartment_type;
  string view;
  string renter_name;
  double amount_due;
};

int main() {
  Apartment complex;
  complex.get_apartment_info();
}
```

That being said, the function, as defined, doesn't make sense as a member of the struct. Chances are, the assignment meant for it to be a free-standing function instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Apartment {
  int building_number;
  int apartment_number;
  string apartment_type;
  string view;
  string renter_name;
  double amount_due;
};

Apartment get_apartment_info() {
  Apartment result;
  cout << "enter building number: ";
  cin >> result.building_number;
  cout << "enter apartment number: ";
  cin >> result.apartment_number;
  cout << "enter apartment type: ";
  cin >> result.apartment_type;
  cout << "enter view: ";
  cin >> result.view;
  cout << "enter your name: ";
  cin >> result.renter_name;
  return result;
};

int main() {
  Apartment complex = get_apartment_info();
}
```

Comment: Wait, I think it is not a good way to giving the full code to OP.

Comment: @K.R.Park you are certainly entitled to your opinion.